# "хорош" и "хватит"

Tags: значения, выбор-слова, синонимы

Очень часто в последнее время встречаю слово "хорош" как синоним на "хватит".

Употребляют его даже в книгах, действие которых развивается в прошлом. Но мне кажется, что в старых книгах я никогда не встречал такое употребление.

А как давно это слово приобрело смысл "хватит"? Не современной ли это жаргон?

Comment: Вы, вероятно, хотели сказать "в последнее время" вместо "напоследок". "Напоследок" == finally; "в последнее время" == lately.

Comment: @mustaccio - русский мне не родной. Но и не надо писать комментарии для таких мелочей - просто отредактируйте вопрос и все. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исходя из своего языкового опыта, я бы определил эти и синонимичные слова следующим образом:

**нейтральная лексика:** `хватит, достаточно`

**разговорный стиль:** `хорош, стоп`

**возвышенный/литературный:** `довольно, будет, полно`

**жаргон:** `харэ` (http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8D)

Из всех этих слов только `харэ`, видимо, появилось относительно недавно. Сомневаюсь, что в этимологическом словаре будет статья на "`хорош`". Лучший способ найти упоминания - это поиск в корпусах русской классики, но у меня такой возможности нет.

Что касается "`хорош`", то я прекрасно могу себе представить, как кучер из произведения Достоевского говорит "`хорош`" в  определённом контексте. Использование `харэ` было бы уже анахронизмом.

Answer (score 10):

На сайте Национального корпуса русского языка, в устном корпусе (на основе фильмов, магнитофонных записей и т.п.) есть [примеры употребления слова "хорош" в смысле "хватит"](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F5%EE%F0%EE%F8&mode=spoken&p=24), которые относятся к середине 30-х годов:

> Яшка! Хороош! Хорош! Хорош! Бюро собралось… [Иван Пырьев, Катерина Виноградская. Партийный билет, к/ф (1936)]
>
> [Офицер] Левей / левей / левей / стоп! Ещё / ещё! Хорош! Готовсь! [На корабле Ушакова] [Михаил Ромм, Александр Штейн. Адмирал Ушаков, к/ф (1953)]
>
> [Пасечник] [командует] Хорош! [Строитель1] Слушай / ты не чувствуешь / чем пахнет / а? [Александр Зархи и др. Высота, к/ф (1957)]

Так что в разговорной речи выражение используется уже как минимум 80 лет.

Но в основном корпусе (текстов) употребления слова "хорош" мне удалось найти только после 1989 года:

> Ну, все, хватит… Хорош! Пошел, вали отсюда… [Николай Коляда. Рогатка (1989)]
>
> ― А вот грузин на рынке мне говорит, ― сказал еще один безымянный собеседник, ― плесни… хорош! [Владимир Крупин. Дети кочегара // Библиотека «Огонек», 1989]

Comment: Отличная работа, коллега!

Answer (score 3):

Это, конечно, разговорное выражение, но появилось оно давно. По крайней мере лет 25 назад оно уже употреблялось.

Answer (score 1):

Хорош = enough
Хватит = sufficient